# Get PhysicalMemoryManufacturer Name not Number

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get my laptop RAM manufacturer, it gives a number as below.
how I can get the name of the manufacturer from code not from GUI programs.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PhysicalMemory | Format-Table -Property Manufacturer
```

### Manufacturer

80AD000080A

D01980000830B
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried, Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName localhost -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object * ?

Comment: What do you get from `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PhysicalMemory).Manufacturer`?

Comment: @NeoTheNerd - from what i can tell, those both return the same info. on my old system, the manufacturer is listed as "none". [*sigh ... [*sigh ...*]

Comment: have you tried searching for the part number? ```wmic memorychip list full```

Comment: On my laptop, Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PhysicalMemory | Format-Table -Property Manufacturer returns "Samsung".